# Java Random Number Fails If statement test in For Loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, random

I have built a simple program to draw a city skyline within a frame with some random elements. The number of buildings will be a random number between [5 - 9], the width and height of each building are also random (within a given range) as is the gap between each building. The problem I am having comes when I try to select a different gap range depending on the amount of buildings. Here is the the section of code in question (I have imported java.util.*;):

```
Random gen = new Random();
int buildNum = gen.nextInt(5) + 5; //generate random number [5 - 9]

for (int i = 0; i < buildNum; i++) 
    {
        //generate random width
        buildWidth = gen.nextInt(26) + 35; //[35 - 60]

        //generate random height
        buildHeight = gen.nextInt(201) + 200; //[200 - 400]

        //instantiate building
        building = new Building (gap, 500 - buildHeight, buildWidth, buildHeight, Color.gray);
        buildingsArray.add(building);

        //draw building
        buildingsArray.get(i).draw (page);

        //generate random gap between building
        if (buildNum < 7) 
        {
            gap += buildWidth + gen.nextInt(16) + 40;
        }

        if (buildNum == 7) 
        {
            gap += buildWidth + gen.nextInt(9) + 15;
        }

        if (buildNum > 7) 
        {
            gap += buildWidth + gen.nextInt(9) + 8;
        }
    }
```

The buildNum variable is initialized with a random number, then that number is used to iterate through. The issue is that when I check the buildNum variable in the three ifs at the bottom, the output does not seem to correspond with what I would expect. I will get 5 buildings with very small gaps (as though it passed the buildNum > 7 test), or I will get 7 buildings with the first six normal, but a very small gap before the seventh building. I'm sure it's something very simple that I am overlooking, but I have been starting at this for hours and tried many different things (including testing buildNum at fixed values 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9, and putting an else clause instead of a third if.) Ultimately, I would like the program to pick a number of buildings between 5 and 9 and then scale the gaps accordingly. I tried factoring in both buildNum and buildWidth, but I couldn't get it to work and settled for this. If anyone has a better way or can shed some light on my problem, I would greatly appreciate it!

Update: I have tested with a constant number of buildings to see what the range of output looks like. The problem is that I would be expecting 5 or 6 buildings to have wide gaps due to the if (buildNum < 7) condition and be progressively smaller due to the other 2 conditions. Instead, I end up with 5 buildings having really really small gaps (6 buildings is fine) and seven and 8 buildings going off the page (even though I've done the math and the gap that is added within the if conditionals would not allow this). There are some helpful comments here already, to answer your questions: Yes, the gap is an absolute position from the left. A small gap is initialized so that the first building does not touch the left side of the frame. Then, buildings are instantiated one at a time with a gap size chosen from those if statements. The position of the next building's left side is determined from a compounding gap variable that includes all previous gaps and all previous building widths. I am especially curious about Lee's comment that the if (buildNum ==7) and (buildNum>7) clauses might never happen. Could you explain that a little further? Wouldn't 8 or 9 satisfy the >7 condition and 7 satisfy the ==7 condition? if not, what can I do to change it? also, here is my constructor:

```
/**
* Constructor: sets background color and frame size
*/

public SkylinePanel()
{
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(600, 500));
    setBackground (Color.black);
}
```

There is not much to it, the real work (including the above shown for loop) is within paintComponent and I've shown everything that is related to the building gaps already. Here is the draw method (it's in my building class):

```
/**
* Draws a building or window with the specified parameters
*/

public void draw (Graphics page) 
{
    page.setColor (color);
    page.fillRect (x, y, width, height);

    winNum = gen.nextInt(8) + 2;

    //generate a random number [2 - 9] of windows to draw on a given building
    for (int i = 0; i < winNum; i++) 
    {
        page.setColor (Color.yellow);
        page.fillRect (gen.nextInt(width - WIN_X) + x, gen.nextInt(height - WIN_Y) + y, WIN_X, WIN_Y);
    }
}
```

Ignore the code about windows, that works fine. I added that after I decided to move on from the gap problem for the time being.

Oh, and just in case anyone needs to see it, here is the constructor of the Building class:

```
public Building (int upperX, int upperY, int buildWidth, int buildHeight, Color shade) 
{
    x = upperX;
    y = upperY;
    width = buildWidth;
    height = buildHeight;
    color = shade;
}
```

Any other thoughts or questions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your gaps are randomized at each iteration. anything can happen

Comment: Seed your `Random` object with a constant for the same random numbers every time the program is run. This will make debugging easier. `new Random(seed);` Also, print the value of every variable after they change or are set. This is a great debugging technique and will show you exactly where you are getting unexpected data.

Comment: What is the problem: please be precise what variable is having the unexpected value, what value you would expect etc - what you have is qualitative. Also the gap variable: where is it initialized?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that `gap` is actually an absolute position (e.g. from left)? What does your `Building` constructor look like? Maybe the problem is in your `draw` method?

Comment: Also, you select a random buildnum from 5 to 9, so the ">7" and "==7" clauses might never happen.